# Captcha recover from another site

Tags: php, curl, captcha

I create  a system for automatic entry of a form from another website via CURL.
But the problem is website have captcha.

Approach I want my system displays the captcha displayed in the form of site to enter the captcha manually but the problem when I picked her image captcha captcha me back another who are not able to send it with the form.

How can I display the captcha displayed in the same form.

Ps : English Is not my mother tongue, sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: I'm currently fighting one guy mass creating accounts on one of my website, and reading this kind of question offend me. So unless you give us a good reason to help you break a protected system, I think this question should be closed.

Comment: The website in question accepts the passage through CURL.
The solution to my script is not sending a max given to their base is just a script for easy entry and always fill captcha shook his hand.
If I want a forced passage shook my question (how broken captcha)

Im so sorry for your website :s

Answer (score 2):

By protecting the form with a CAPTCHA, the author has obviously attempted to make it difficult for you to do what you are doing for a reason. That is CAPTCHA are designed to prevent automatic entry. I would personally respect this.

However, should you decide to go ahead, the easiest way I have found to redisplay website content, is to pull the actual content itself. So use cURL or any other prefered method to get the actual HTML of the form, parse it to get the captcha image and input field name/id. Display the captcha image and presumably have a human solve it or run it through whatever CAPTCHA breaker you run, then use the input field name/id to submit that solution back with the rest of the form.

Again, do not do the above as it really is an inconsiderate thing to do. In your comment above, you say that the website accepts the passage through cURL. If they actually allowed this, then there would be a url to connect to that either provided you a challenge to redisplay specifically, did not request the CAPTCHA, or some other such mechanism. This leaves either the option that you have taken the simple ability to connect to the website with cURL as permission (it is not as a cURL connection is the same as any other connection comming accross the Internet) or that the webmaster for the website you are connecting to needs to get on the ball with creating an actual interphase for scripts like yours.

Either way, I am sure that everyone on here would encourage you to be a good citizen of the InterWebz and simply stick with not attempting to break things designed to keep out automated scripts.

Comment: Thank you for your words but I found a solution using C # I called the page in a webbrouser and I took a picture of the brouser and as I could make out the captcha